How to enable fold by indent
I would like to enable content folding by indent.
e.g.
aaaa
  bbbb
  bbbb
    cccc

can be fold to
aaaa
  bbbb
  bbbb

or even further
aaaa

So far I have set in .vimrc
set shiftwidth=0
set tabstop=2
set foldmethod=indent               
set foldminlines=0                  
set foldtext='\ '
set fillchars=fold:\ 

However it still would not fold. May I ask what is missing?

Works for me with vim --clean and the options above.

Could you clarify what you mean by "it would not fold"? What do you do exactly?

@romainl I press spacebar and the rows won't fold.

@Friedrich I'm confused.. i ran "gvim --clean" from windows command prompt, and then key in all those set setting options, and it still does not fold. what could go wrong? actually i recently reinstalled my laptop, previous folding works fine.

@athos The command for folding is zf maybe you used to have a mapping for spacebar and it's not there anymore? Does it fold when you use zf?

Why do you expect <space> to do any folding? That command is totally unrelated.

Use za or zc to toggle or close folds. Are you maybe confusing foldtext (set to space in your options) with the commands to fold?

oh~~~~~~~~ silly me.... thank you @romainl and Friedrich

it's a simple and silly mistake -- would you prefer it be closed or i add a simple answer to wrap things off? @Friedrich

@Friedrich done :)

As the comments explained, the settings above actually enabled folding by indent, typing za (one level) or zA (all levels) will see the folding/unfolding effect.
What confused me is that I'm used to fold/unfold by pressing the spacebar. To enable that, I added in .vimrc:
nnoremap <Space> za


It usually helps to enable the foldcolumn, which makes it quiet obvious, if a fold has been found. Try :set foldcolumn=5  or something similar

cool, learnt something new :)

Also see https://github.com/benknoble/vim-auto-origami if you work with folds a lot and find the foldcolumn helpful
